# Spring/Tomcat JDBC initialization

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc

I have a Spring REST application deployed to a Tomcat server. I had placed a schema.sql file inside the resources folder that I use to recreate database on local test/development scenarios.

However, when Tomcat starts up, it seemed to run this script against the database.

In the logs, I have the following entry for this:

`2016-01-26 17:30:33.543  INFO 2105 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/xxxx/WEB-INF/classes/schema.sql]`

I find it a bit strange and wonder why does this happen.

Can anybody provide insights into this?

I tried googling as usual, and could not find any satisfactory results.

Comment: The resources folder is for files that you want deployed *with* the webapp, as part of the classpath. If that is not what you want, you should put the file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

> Spring JDBC has a `DataSource` initializer feature. Spring Boot enables it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations **`schema.sql`** and `data.sql` (in the root of the classpath).